# intermittent 404 on aws cloudfront.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My web server (Nginx) is hosted on aws ec2 linux instance and for caching purpose we are using cloudfront . we have observed we are getting intermittent 404 issue on cloudfront object . we came to know this intermittent issue from **popular object** tab on cloudfront . when we checked cloudfront object url its giving proper output . can any one know how to resolve this intermittent 404 issue?

Comment: You'll need to start by correlating the CloudFront logs with your origin server logs.  Just because an object is popular does not mean it is always being served from the cache -- this depends on the geographic distribution of the viewers.  You need to establish where the issue is -- whether in CloudFront or (more likely) at the origin.

Comment: cloudfront will serve the object from 1 of over 100 different locations around the world, depending on where the request comes from. Check through your logs and CF logs to see where the issue is. Also remember, each CF edge location gets its cache populated only when a request is made to that location, and some of them might have cached 404 responses from your origin.